# Why does using the default proxy credentials not result in an automatic second http request following a 407 response?

Tags: c#, proxy, fiddler, defaultnetworkcredentials

I have set up fiddler as a proxy server requiring authentication following [these instructions](https://jegansblog.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/setup-fiddler-as-proxy-server-with-basic-authentication/).

When I explicitly set the credentials I've set in Fiddler in my `HttpClientHandler`:

```cs
this.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
this.Proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("sweet name", "sweet password");
```

Then in Fiddler I get 2 http requests, a 407 and an automatic 200, and the request succeeds:

[image: 407 and 200 response]

However, when I try use the default credentials:

```cs
this.Proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
this.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Then in Fiddler I only get one request, a 407, and the request fails:

[image]

Why is there no automatic retry with the default credentials like there is when I explicitly set the proxy credentials?

Comment: As you have Fiddler running as proxy you can simply check the requests if they are different, especially the two 407 requests.

Comment: The two 407 requests look identical :/  I think the issue is that the fiddler proxy uses basic authentication, and maybe the default credentials don't support that.

Comment: Would make sense. The documentation states `The DefaultCredentials property applies only to NTLM, negotiate, and Kerberos-based authentication.` Hence no username/password authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Robert in a comment, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netcore-3.1) says:

`The DefaultCredentials property applies only to NTLM, negotiate, and Kerberos-based authentication.`

Hence it makes sense that there is no automatic second http request following a 407 response when the proxy uses basic authentication.